# TCP Socket doesn't send all the data

Tags: vb.net, sockets, tcpclient

I'm trying to send about 250KBytes but I get cut at 8KBytes
I doesn't need any answer from the remote server.
I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.
Is like the tx doesn't change the outbuffer size.

```
Private Function SendReport7B(ByVal Msg As String, ByVal Host As String, ByVal Port As String) As String
    Try
        Dim Msgs() As String
        Dim Tx As New TcpClient()

        Dim stream As NetworkStream = Nothing
        Dim LingerMode As New LingerOption(True, 1)
        'Dim BSize As Integer

        Tx.NoDelay = True
        Tx.LingerState = LingerMode
        Tx.SendTimeout = 5000

        If Msg.Length > Tx.SendBufferSize Then
            Tx.SendBufferSize = Msg.Length + 256
        End If

        Tx.Connect(Host, Port)

        Msgs = Msg.Split(Chr(10))

        ' Translate the passed message into ASCII and store it as a Byte array.
        Dim data As [Byte]() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Msg)

        ' Get a client stream for reading and writing.
        '  Stream stream = client.GetStream();
        stream = Tx.GetStream()
        'stream.WriteTimeout = 100
        ' Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)

      
        Tx.Close()

        Return "OK" 'responseData
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return "Error: " & ex.Message
    End Try

End Function
```

Comment: Have you tried performing an `Await client.FlushAsync()` before you close? What is `Msgs = Msg.Split(Chr(10))` for?

Comment: Nope, I was not aware of that. I just client.flush()?

Comment: @CaiusJard You guys mean `await stream.FlushAsync()`. Which would also need `ConnectAsync()` etc.

Comment: Yes, sorry.. That

Comment: @Jimi I think there's something with buffer size because I get 8192bytes out of 250Kbytes

Comment: I don't know why you're setting `Tx.SendBufferSize = Msg.Length + 256`, it doesnt' look like you're sending a custom packet that the receiver can interpret to decode the length of the data stream. I also don't know what's the use of this: `Msgs = Msg.Split(Chr(10))`, since you send the `Msg` string after (maybe a second thought?). Not sure you can use `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes()` on either sender or receiver side, since I don't know about the content of the string. The receiver side, probably closes the connection when it *thinks* that data is complete, probably reading a string, when it's not.

Comment: Anyway, it looks like the problem is on the receiver side. If it's your code, then you should probably post that.

Comment: @Jimi The packet is a string with variable length from 100bytes to 250KBytes. The split line was a previous version where I send the big packet line by line. The string is basically text. I just added a 3 seconds delay before Tx.Close() and works ok, at least for 1K lines(80Kbytes).

Comment: @Jimi There's any way to know when the output buffer is empty?

Comment: You need to care about the input buffer. The methods you're using now are synchronous. `Write()` will return when all the buffer content has been copied to the Socket stream or the the other side closes the Connection. You can wait while `Connected` is `true`, after you have written your data. Possibly with a time-out.

Comment: @Jimi Yes, that was what I know, the write process should lock until the transmission ends, that's how it was working 2 years ago. Today I tried this code again and suddenly the write process doesn't lock as before. As far I know the remote server never closes the connection so the Connected property always will be true. So I don't know how to know when the remote server has received the whole data.

Comment: What is that you're sending? Are you sure it can be treated as ASCII? Maybe you're sending double `0`s (`\0\0`) and the other side *thinks* that the string is terminated and closes the connection. Is the connection closed after you flush the stream? Did  you make a `while` loop, waiting for `.Connected = false` (with a Timeout)? Have you set `SendTimeout` to a higher value? Do you know what the other side is expecting to receive? Don't you have an exchange protocol of sort, that specifies the data length in advance? etc.

Comment: @Jimi Yes, is pure text, the only strange data is a pipe | character. As I said before, if I add a delay before the Tx.Close() it works ok. So if there's any way to know that the whole data was received by the server it will work fine. Unfortunately the protocol designer doesn't know too much about programming and made a really bad design. The client is supposed to send the data and close the port, but there's no ACK from server, that will let me know if the server just received the whole data and I will close the port properly and not early as now.